# Passing Integer from Android Home Screen Widget to an Activity opened by the Android Home Screen

Tags: android, widget, homescreen

How can we pass Android Home Screen Widget info ( putExtra maybe ) to an Activity.. What particular method callback will handle this one?

Comment: seems that when I place putIntExtra on the Intent, it doesnt update it properly

Answer (score 2):

Use `putIntExtra()` on the `Intent` you place in the `PendingIntent`.

> seems that when I place putIntExtra on
>   the Intent, it doesnt update it
>   properly

Try using `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` when you create your `PendingIntent`.